# Why is infinite object creation not throwing OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Why am I not getting OutOfMemoryError with the below code?

```
class OutOfMemoryErrorTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object obj;

        while(true){
            obj = new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running with Java 8.

Comment: GarbageCollection

Comment: you are creating *one* object in an infinite loop. there is always one object in memory.

Comment: basically, as soon as your while loop meets it closing bracket, the local variable within is available for garbage collection

Comment: Even after moving the obj reference from local to global , I am not seeing outofmemoryerror . Why?

Comment: You have *one* reference to *one* object. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The obj will be marked collectable after each loop, so it will be collected.

```
    while(true){
        Object obj = new Object(); //no further reference, so obj will be collected
    }
```

If you need to test OOM, you should save the reference of obj to a LinkedList.

```
    List refs = new LinkedList();
    while (true) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        refs.add(obj);
    }
```

Then you will get the OOM as you wanted. And you can use a smaller heap to reach OOM sooner.

Comment: JIT can prove that this object is not used, at all - and might optimize the allocation away entirely. Not even that `LinkedList` example is perfect, since you are not using it either, JIT is again free to throw that away

Comment: @Eugene, you are right . Saving into LinkedList also not giving OOM error.

Comment: @JavaUser I don't know if any JIT does that in practice, but these kind of methods, at least in theory, can be made by JIT as NO-OP

Comment: @Eugene Could you please provide some link to that?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I don't think I have one, but think about it: if that method has no side-effects, why execute it in the first place?

Comment: The OOM will happen. Use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, we can get the heapdump file. There are a great many object instances and LinkedList$Node instances. And the object instances is smaller than LinkedList$Node instances.

Comment: @Eugene and sanigo , I am seein OOM in linkedlist case after a long time.

Comment: @JavaUser LinkedList$Node instance is larger that the object instance, but there are indeed a huge number of object instances in heap. You can use a bit longer random strings to test.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not save the object reference, so garbage collector remove the created objects. if you add these objects to List then it will happened.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Comments should not be used specifically for answering questions. That's what the "Your Answer" section of the page is for.

Comment: i disagree. comments can be used to answer trivial, short answers. it is quite common

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Sure, but there's no reason to call out someone who answers a question just because someone else answered it in a comment. It's like you're scolding someone for following a rule.

Comment: yes there is reason. fishing for points by answering trivial questions is misdemeanor that should be discouraged. especially coming from someone with your rep.

Comment: @MohsenKashi the correct way to put it would be *it might* happen, or *happens under the current implementation* or *on my laptop* - because JIT might throw that entire allocation away - since it is not used in any way

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Plenty of "trivial questions" get answered every day, from users with 1 rep to users with well over 100k rep. And so what? I'm not saying there aren't people like that on SE, but not everyone answers questions for the rep, and policing this won't accomplish anything.

Comment: @TNT, I do not go around hunting for answers to trivial questions. this question (which probably has a duplicate) was already answered (multiple times) in comments by the time this answer was posted. not only this answer is trivial, it is also redundant.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I'm not saying you do. What I am suggesting, though, is that the information provided in the comments does answer the question, and so there's nothing wrong with putting it into an actual answer to this post. I see no issue with this (and I don't see how this answer is redundant), but we may just have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly it simply gets removed by the garbage collector cause you create it in a loop. Secondly it could be you have so much memory that you just have to wait long. So when u fixed the garbage collector thing you may wait long. Try this code i found on https://crunchify.com/how-to-generate-out-of-memory-oom-in-java-programatically/

```
package test;

public class OutOfMemoryErrorTest {

    /**
     * @author Crunchify.com
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OutOfMemoryErrorTest memoryTest = new OutOfMemoryErrorTest();
        memoryTest.generateOOM();
    }

    public void generateOOM() throws Exception {
        int iteratorValue = 20;
        System.out.println("\n=================> OOM test started..\n");
        for (int outerIterator = 1; outerIterator < 20; outerIterator++) {
            System.out.println("Iteration " + outerIterator + " Free Mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
            int loop1 = 2;
            int[] memoryFillIntVar = new int[iteratorValue];
            // feel memoryFillIntVar array in loop..
            do {
                memoryFillIntVar[loop1] = 0;
                loop1--;
            } while (loop1 > 0);
            iteratorValue = iteratorValue * 5;
            System.out.println("\nRequired Memory for next loop: " + iteratorValue);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```